# Differences between environments when installing a node.js application

Tags: node.js

I'm experiencing the following error situation, while trying to install a `node.js`-based application (or, more accurately, platform, specifically, Binder - I'm performing a custom deployment, documented [here](https://github.com/binder-project/binder-docs/blob/master/markdown/custom-deployments.md)). I have performed a comprehensive investigation and attempted to fix my environment, based on advice I ran across online, however, as of now the problem persists. What it interesting is that one of my colleagues was able to easily install relevant subsystem on her Mac laptop, whereas my Ubuntu 14.04-based server environment seems to be problematic.

One more clarification before presenting the promised output is that I'm performing the installation as `root` indirectly, that is, logged in as me (`ablekh`) and then switched to the `sudo` mode (`sudo -s`) - the side effect of this is that `$HOME` points to `/home/ablekh`. Considering this, I made sure relevant directories under my user home (`.nvm` and `.binder`) have sufficient access modes to compensate for discrepancy in the ownership.

```
npm WARN deprecated wrench@1.5.9: wrench.js is deprecated! You should check out fs-extra (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) for any operations you were using wrench for. Thanks for all the usage over the years.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
/home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin/binder-control -> /home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/binder-control/bin/binder-control

> fibers@1.0.14 install /home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/binder-control/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-v8-5.1` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting

> websocket@1.0.23 install /home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/binder-control/node_modules/websocket
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/binder-control/node_modules/websocket/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/binder-control/node_modules/websocket/build'

> binder-db@1.0.1 postinstall /home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/binder-control/node_modules/binder-db
> node scripts/postinstall.js

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/ablekh/.binder/db.conf'
    at Error (native)
/home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib
└── (empty)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /binder-control/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin/node" "/home/ablekh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin/npm" "install" "binder-control" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! binder-db@1.0.1 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the binder-db@1.0.1 postinstall script 'node scripts/postinstall.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the binder-db package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/postinstall.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs binder-db
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls binder-db
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ablekh/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: Need the npm log or something with the actual error message from postinstall script.  Try running postinstall manually.

Comment: @JasonLivesay Appreciate your attention. Isn't `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/ablekh/.binder/db.conf'` the error or, at least, the root error in this case? What log level should I set for you? When I tried to run postinstall script, it didn't appear in the directory mentioned in the output above. Sorry, I have zero experience with node-related stuff. Is there any difference between running the installation steps as regular user and as superuser, if I want system to be available globally for all users (I thought that `-g` flag does that, but it is present not in all steps)?

Comment: I missed the eaccess part of the log before sorry.  I am guessing its related to the sudo command somehow.  Try removing and reinstalling as before with -g but no sudo, but first change npm config prefix to a hidden folder off of your user home dir, option 2 here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions